# Objective-C properties within the header file - IOS

Tags: properties, uiviewcontroller

I am new to IOS and after following a number of online tutorials, I came across a situation where the properties of the `ViewController` Class where being placed within curly brackets of the `@interface`.  Some UI properties were being placed as `@properties` as well as within `@interface`, and some just within the latter.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSString *string;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *string;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *date;

@end
```

Are the properties within the `@interface` are the same as private properties or is this something else?

Answer (score 0):

According to me the variables within the `@interface` curly brackets are private variable. but when you set `@property` for them, these become protected variable. So when you `#import` the class then you can access them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So when you mean protected, does that mean protected as referred to in general programming?

Comment: yap, kind of that... explicitly variable which can be access by inheriting the class..